# Simulation of Pepper Robot in Gazebo

Tags: pepper, gazebo-simu, choregraphe

How to sync Choregraphe software with the gazebo?
I have simulated the robot in the gazebo with the help of this
[repository](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_virtual)

This repository only gives me control through [moveit](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/pepper_moveit_config/blob/master/README.rst), which I don't want.
How can I program the pepper robot in choregraphe and simulate it in the gazebo?
Thank you

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask great questions.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod is it good enough now?

Comment: As it stands the question is too broad. It expects the community to click links and examine Github repositories. Instead, include inline the code that you have tried. Detail the expected results and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Gazebo will simulate a Pepper by publishing and subscribing to all the required ROS topics. But it will not start NAOqi, and it will not provide an endpoint for Choregraphe to connect to.